# actionmailer question on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

I'm trying to convert this code

```
def password_reset_instructions(user)
    subject       "Registered"
    recipients    user.email
    body          :edit_password_reset_url => edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)
end
```

to this code

```
def password_reset_instructions(user)
  @user = user
   mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")
end
```

My problem is i don't know where to put the code below.

```
:edit_password_reset_url => edit_password_reset_url(user.perishable_token)"
```

I am using authlogic on rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, Mailers work just like controllers. You can use the instance variable of the user in the accompanying view.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try this:

```
      def password_reset_instructions(user)
          @edit_password_reset_url = edit_password_reset_path(user.perishable_token)
          mail(
             :subject    => "Password Reset Instructions",
             :recipients => user.email
          )
      end
```